# polyTypeOf is mysterious

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

[PolyTypeable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/polytypeable/latest/doc/html/Data-PolyTypeable.html) is an analog of Typeable for polymorphic types. But it works rather unpredictably:

```
ghci> :t show
show :: Show a => a -> String
ghci> polyTypeOf show
a1 -> [Char]
ghci> :t fromEnum 
fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int
ghci> polyTypeOf fromEnum 

<interactive>:1:12:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Enum a0) arising from a use of `fromEnum'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `polyTypeOf', namely `fromEnum'
    In the expression: polyTypeOf fromEnum
    In an equation for `it': it = polyTypeOf fromEnum
```

The library source code is quite hard to understand, could you explain why does `polyTypeOf` accept certain set of arguments and fails to accept other, even very similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is the same as for

```
Prelude> show undefined
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude> fromEnum undefined

<interactive>:0:1:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Enum a0) arising from a use of `fromEnum'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: fromEnum undefined
    In an equation for `it': it = fromEnum undefined
```

namely, ghci's extended defaulting rules allow it to resolve the ambiguity for a `Show` constraint, but not for an `Enum` constraint. If you try to compile a source file with `foo = polyTypeOf show`, you also get an ambiguous type variable error (unless you use `{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}`).

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of it, since `polyTypeOf show` is not something default like `() -> String`.

Comment: And is there a way to make `polyTypeOf fromEnum` and similar work? perhaps with setting some `default (...)`s?